# After removing selected item from list view, binding doesn't change

Tags: c#, forms, xamarin

I'm writing xamarin forms app and I have problem with binding `SelectedItem` from `ListView`. Everything is fine until `SelectedItem` is removing from `ObservableCollection`. After this operation `SelectedItem` still contains previous value, but it should be equal `null`.

Why doesn't it work and how to repair it.

```
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Clients}" SelectionMode="Single" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedSocket}">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextCell Text="{Binding HostEntry.HostName}" />
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>

public ObservableCollection<TcpSocket> Clients { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<TcpSocket>();
private TcpSocket _SelectedSocket { get; set; }
public TcpSocket SelectedSocket
{
    get => _SelectedSocket;
    set
    {
        _SelectedSocket = value;
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(SelectedSocket)));
    }
}
```

And after click button something like that:

```
Clients.Remove(SelectedSocket);
```

Comment: set it to null manually then

Comment: but i don't know why it doesn't change alone

Comment: Could you provide a bit of your code ? Binding xaml and ViewModel selectedItem property, how do you remove it ?

Comment: You have to share the XAML or code showing the binding and the code source of the binding at a minimum please.

Comment: TcpSocket is my class

Comment: Ok ... What I think right now is that you are removing the SelectedItem form your observable collection, but it does not raise the SelectedItem property change, so what you should do is when you remove the SelectedItem from ObservableCollection, raise it manually.

Comment: I added this after remove:
PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Clients)));
But it doesn't change anything

Answer (score 0):

Manually set the desired property to null after removing it from the collection so the property changed even can be raised.

```
//...

public void OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    Clients.Remove(SelectedSocket); //raises collection changed
    SelectedSocket = null; //raises property changed
}

//...
```